# ORDER BY a tabla SQL empezando desde un valor en especifico

Tags: php, sql, formularios

estoy haciendo un formulario de registro y en una parte solicito la nacionalidad de la persona, la cual es seleccionada de una tabla en SQL

```
    <p style="text-align:center;"><label><select id="lista" name="Nacionalidad">
                <?php
                include 'conexion.php';
                $consulta = "SELECT CveNacion,Nacionalidad FROM catnacion";
                $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
                ?>
                <form action="" method="post" class="form-login">
                    <?php foreach ($resultado as  $opciones) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $opciones['Nacionalidad'] ?>">
                            <?php echo $opciones['CveNacion'].' '.substr($opciones['Nacionalidad'],0,15)  ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
            </select></label></p>
```

El problema es que al efectuar el `$consulta = "SELECT CveNacion,Nacionalidad FROM catnacion";` se despliega de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que el primer valor que se muestre sea México:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado efectuar un ORDER BY empezando desde la M talque así, `SELECT CveNacion,Nacionalidad FROM catnacion ORDER BY Nacionalidad>"M"`, pero no lo hace como yo quiero, hay alguna forma que desde la consulta me muestre primero ese resultado o lo puedo hacer directamente en el formulario, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías poner un `CASE` en la expresión `ORDER BY` para que coloque primero a México y los valores que requieras.

```
$consulta = "SELECT CveNacion,Nacionalidad FROM catnacion ORDER BY CASE WHEN CveNacion = 'MEX' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, CveNacion ";
```

Comment: Si funciono perfecto la consulta, muestra MEX MEXICO como primer resultado muchas gracas

Answer (score 1):

Si note importa como se muestre el resto de los datos lo que yo haría para que se muestre por default el valor de México sería agregar una condicion:

```
<?php if( $opciones['CveNacion'] === 'MEX' ) echo 'selected' ?>
```

Quedando así:

```
<option value="<?php echo $opciones['Nacionalidad'] ?>"  <?php if( $opciones['CveNacion'] === 'MEX' ) echo 'selected' ?>>
<?php echo $opciones['CveNacion'].' '.substr($opciones['Nacionalidad'],0,15)  ?></option>
```

Luego entonces siempre te mostrará por default México

Comment: Es buena opción pero funciono perfecto haciéndolo directo desde la consulta, muchas graias